# Why, in some situations, does "de" remain neutral and not become "do/da" despite being followed by a noun?

Tags: gramática

I saw  a guide to the preposition "de" and realised some of the time it precedes a noun but does not take on the determinant

"um filme de ação"

"um apartamento de três quartos"

I was wondering if there was any rule as to why the correct phrasing is not "do ação" or "dos três quartos"

Answer (score 6):

You say *fime **de** ação*, not ***da** ação*, because we mean action in general, not a particular action: it’s an *action movie*, not a *movie of **the** action*. Likewise, *apartamento **de** três quartos*, not ***dos** três quartos*, because we just mean three rooms in general, not three particular rooms: a *three-room apartment*, not *apartment of **the** three rooms*. But you could say *o apartamento dos três quartos amarelos* if you meant an apartment with three particular yellow rooms that caught our attention.

And *uma chave **de** carro* is simply a *car key*, it could be any car. *Uma chave **do** carro* is a key of a particular car, like *uma chave do carro do João*. *Roupa de criança* is clothing for children in general; *roupa da criança* is a particular child’s (perhaps our own) clothing.

It often works as in English. *cadeira (feita) **de** madeira* (chair made of wood, wooden chair), but *cadeira feita **da** madeira **da** árvore que nós abatemos* (*from **the** wood of **the** tree that*…)

This distinction—*de* for general, *do, da* for particular items—will see you through in many cases, but it doesn’t cover everything. For instance we say *mosca da fruta* (fruit fly, not any particular fruit), *bicho da madeira* (woodlouse; *bicho de madeira* sounds like a toy bug or animal made of wood), or *bicho do mato* (literally ’animal from the bush, woods’; figuratively ’a shy person’).